# MySQL, breakout multiple fields from a table into one column

Tags: mysql, union-all, into-outfile

I have a table that has several part number columns:  `PN1`, `PN2`, `PN3`, `otherData`.

I want to create an efficient MySQL query that will collapse the part number columns into one column called `PN` that links the part numbers to otherData.

This transformation is necessary for our business logic.  I have a query below that works correctly, but we need to improve performance drastically.

Is there a better way to do the following?

SQL Query which transforms the data correctly, but is inefficient:

```
SELECT 'Pn', 'Mfg', 'TableId', 'SourceColumn', 'OtherData'
SELECT PN1, Mfg, '26', 'PN1', OtherData FROM Table
UNION ALL
SELECT PN2, Mfg, '26', 'PN2', OtherData FROM Table
UNION ALL
SELECT PN3, Mfg, '26', 'PN3', OtherData FROM Table
UNION ALL
SELECT PN4, Mfg, '26', 'PN4', OtherData 
INTO OUTFILE 'XXX.dat'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM Table d;
```

The input table looks like the following table:

```
|  PN1  |  PN2  |  PN3    |  PN4    |  MFG  |  TableId  |  OtherData  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  asdf |  abde |  12354  |  asdfc  |  2    |  26       |  0.2456     |
|  nupo |  1354 |  null   |  null   |  2    |  26       |  1.53       |
|  ...  |  ...  |  ...    |  ...    |  ...  |  ...      |  ...        |
|  ...  |  ...  |  ...    |  ...    |  ...  |  ...      |  ...        |
|  ...  |  ...  |  ...    |  ...    |  ...  |  ...      |  ...        |
```

I want the output `.dat` file to look like this:

```
"Pn",    "Mfg", "TableId",  "SourceColumn","OtherData"
"asdf",  2,     26,         "PN1",         0.2456
"abde",  2,     26,         "PN2",         0.2456
"12354", 2,     26,         "PN3",         0.2456
"asdfc", 2,     26,         "PN4",         0.2456
"nupo",  2,     26,         "PN1",         1.53
"1354",  2,     26,         "PN2",         1.53
...
```

Notice that the PN1 through PN4 was collapsed into PN.

Is there a faster way to do this kind of transformation in MySQL?

Comment: You can probably do it with a stored procedure that creates a dynamic query. I'm not sure how to write this, though.

Comment: what do you mean "group_concat in reverse"? Show example input and output data to demonstrate what you mean. Also, it's still a mystery to us what you are *really* trying to do (your question seems to be about a solution to a problem, but there may be a better way).

Comment: Just edited the question to make it (hopefully) clearer

Comment: please show real results, your query can't be exporting the given output

Comment: It's not.  When I add the "INTO" clause it breaks.  That's what I meant by "sort of".  The output is what I want to get, not what I am getting.  Just added a note about the INTO OUTFILE clause

Comment: Have added additional information to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cross posted this question under the database administrators page over at

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35514/better-query-to-select-multiple-columns-into-a-single-output-column

It appears that the query is (at least for MySQL) the best I can do for the time being.  If MySQL ever implements support for `PIVOT` / `UNPIVOT` then this question should be revisited.